# Record update for dynamically-resolved field name

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, generic-programming

I have a record defined like below:

```
data MyData = MyData
    { name :: String
    , addr :: String
     ... a lot of other fields of String type
    }
```

Next I want to create list of pairs `(String, fieldName)`, something like this:

```
fields =
  [ ("NAME", name)
  , ("ADDRESS", addr)
  , ... and for other fields
  ]
```

And finally I need a function which can get empty record of type `MyData` and fill it dynamically field by field, like this:

```
initByStrings strs = foldl (\ d (x, y) -> d{y=(findIn x strs)}) emptyMyData fields
```

Is a behaviour like this possible in Haskell without long monotonic constructions like below?

```
...
lst = map (\ x -> findIn x strs) fields
f lst where
    f (name:addr:...) = MyData name addr ...
```

Comment: You attempt to convert a list to MyData data type?

Comment: @assembly.jc yes, but this list is created statically in sources only for centralised data management instead of repeating same strings a lot of time in code in constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was created in this way:

List of fields has a function which updates corresponding field in record :

```
fields =
  [ ("NAME", (\d x -> d{name=x}))
  , ("ADDRESS", (\d x -> d{addr=x}))
  , ... and for other fields
  ]
```

Function which initializes `MyData` record looks like:

```
 initByStrings strs = foldl (\ d (x, y) -> y d(findIn x strs)}) emptyMyData fields
```

So records fields can be updated one by one from `foldl` using some external function wich resolver string value from string name of field from list.

Answer (score 5):

That's a use case for generics.

```
import GHC.Generics

data MyData = MyData
  { ...
  } deriving (Generic)  -- extension: DerivingGeneric
```

The `Generic` type class has an associated type `Rep` and a method `to` (and `from`)

```
to :: MyData -> Rep MyData p {- ignore the p -}
```

`Rep MyData` unfolds to a type constructed with `M1`, `(:*:)` and `K1`:

```
Rep MyData =
  M1 D _ (
    M1 C _ (
        ( M1 S _ (K1 _ String) )
      :*:
        ( M1 S _ (K1 _ String) )
    )
  )
-- the things hidden by underscores carry metadata about MyData
-- (type name, constructor name, field names, whether fields are lazy, etc.).
```

So if you can write a function that works for many combinations of `M1`, `(:*:)`, `K1`, you can then obtain a function on `MyData` by composition with `to`.

```
class GFromMap r where
  gFromMap :: Map String String -> Maybe (r p)  -- always ignore the p

-- extension: FlexibleContexts
fromMap :: (Generic a, GFromMap (Rep a)) => Map String String -> Maybe a
fromMap m = to <$> gFromMap m
```

We need four instances of `GFromMap`. Two for the `M1 D` and `M1 C` newtypes carrying information about `MyData` that we don't care about (type name, constructor names).

```
-- extension: FlexibleInstances
instance GFromMap r => GFromMap (M1 D d r) where
  gFromMap m = M1 <$> gFromMap m

instance GFromMap r => GFromMap (M1 C c r) where
  gFromMap m = M1 <$> gFromMap m
```

One for products `(:*:)`

```
-- extension: TypeOperators
instance (GFromMap r1, GFromMap r2) => GFromMap (r1 :*: r2) where
  gFromMap m = (:*:) <$> gFromMap m <*> gFromMap m
```

And one for fields, here we need to grab the field name from the metadata `s` associated with the `M1 S` newtype, using the `Selector` type class.

```
-- extension: ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies
-- the type equality (a ~ String) is for better error messages when
-- a record has a field not of type String
instance (a ~ String, Selector s) => GFromMap (M1 S s (K1 i a)) where
  gFromMap m = M1 <$> K1 <$> Map.lookup fdName m
    where fdName = toUpper <$> selName (undefined :: _t s _r _a)  -- we can refer to s thanks to ScopedTypeVariables
```

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/f27c078faec11487df2828cdfb81752a